# Setup Github SSH Keys with Ubuntu: Extracted key into Github but still getting asked for username and pw when pushing

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal, key

I watched a YouTube tutorial on how to setup SSH keys with Ubuntu.  I have a screen shot of all the code I input into the terminal.

I was able to extract out a SSH key.

[image]

I copy the entire key and paste it into the SSH Keys section of Github.  It accepts it.

But when I go to push local files into my github I get asked for the username and password again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are a number of tutorials out there, such as [this one](https://build-me-the-docs-please.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Using_Git/SetUpSSHForGit.html).

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your remote URL

```
 cd /path/to/my/repo
 git remote -v
```

It should be an SSH URL `git@github.com/<myGitHubUsername>/<myrepo>`

Second, [check that `ssh -Tv git@github.com`](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection) ends with `Hi username! You've successfully authenticated`

Comment: I'm getting a git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @PineNuts0 That is the issue right there: make sure your public key is registered to your account: https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account